# Unable to add values to a specific table in phpmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I created a form that using `php` will be able to post 2 text variables 1 photo and a date to a table of my server. For some reason the `wampserver` wont allow me to complete this action and post this message

> "Forbidden" "You don't have permission to access /< on this server."

The strange of my problem is that it allows another form to add members to another table on the same server but not this form.

I have searched and realized that the error message I get is common but the conditions are not common.
 I tried editing `httpd.conf`, recreating the whole server and tables and also reinstalling the wampserver with no positive results
Any assistance welcome and sorry if the conditions of this problem are common but I havent manage to find a post with similar conditions

Comment: did you give permission to insert value to that user?

Comment: The whole database has full priviledges on all users

Answer (score 1):

Change httpd.conf. by default you will have

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Change to

```
<Directory />
 Require all granted #for apache version 2.4
</Directory>
```

Edited

Comment: I did that and I have no change. It still denies me  to add values to the specific table

Comment: what is your apache version

Comment: then use 'Require all granted' in place of 'Allow from all'

Comment: I will try your advice and I would like to also mention that I have this issue in the apache error log that I just saw

[Wed Oct 07 16:43:16.142269 2015] [core:error] [pid 1664:tid 788] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:52060] AH00127: Cannot map POST /%3C?%20echo%20$PHP_SELF;%20?%3E HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/NewsManagement.php

Comment: For some reason it doesnt allow me to actually answer the question so problem solved. there was a mistake in the coding and specifically at the options of the form that added values to the database. after changing the form options it worked. thanks for your help

    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addNewsForm">

instead of the

    <form method="post" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addNewsForm">